# Create azure website programatically in C#

Tags: powershell, azure, msdeploy, webdeploy, azure-management-api

I want to create/update the websites/cloud services in Azure in C#. My objective is to deploy the website/cloud service in Azure without any user intervention.

Can anyone please help me to resolve below queries?

1. Can we manage Azure websites/cloud services using C# code? If yes then how (any library/api/nuget package)?
2. If it is not possible in C#, then what are other options to achieve this? I read WebDeploy(MsDeploy), powershell can do this work but I am not sure which one is best in this scenario and how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on your scenario. If you have got a system to run your powershell script from, this might be a good option (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/) You could also use the cross platform command line tools to script your deployment / web app creation. There are different other options, especially for continous deployment to a web app. You can for example connect your github repo to an existing web app and deploy from that repository.

The C# library you were looking for should be this one:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/src/ResourceManagement/WebSite